# Htaccess replace '?' with 'q'

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have backed up a site from archive.org, an since "?" is not a valid character in a file I have saved replaced the "?" with a "q" when saving the files with query arguments.

Eg. when I crawled the url

> http://example.com/test?cond=true

I saved it as

> testqcond=true

Now, I have reuploaded the site and I want a request to http://example.com/test?cond=true to read the file **testqcond=true** as a response.
(I need to do this since I don't have the server side code and thus cannot process the query other than the statically saved file with the query)

Thus I need to change the htaccess file to replace ? with q when looking for files.

Usually I'd just replace the character in htaccess but seeing as this is the query string I cannot.

How could this be done?

I'd imagine the process would go like this:

1. Check if a query string is present
2. Look for a file named URL + q + QUERYARGUMENTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule to convert `?` in query to `q`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}q%{QUERY_STRING}? [L]
```

Comment: Hmm I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work. It just seems to return the same query string, eg. http://example.com/test?cond=true

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly!
By the way, is there any way to keep the '?' in the URL but just search for files with 'q' instead of '?'

Comment: You can remove `R=302` from above rule and then URL will keep showing `?` but internally it will be `q`

Comment: YES that was exactly what I wanted!
Thanks so much!